# Why is `& 0xff` executed like this in Ruby source code?

Tags: c, ruby

in ruby.h, I find it difficult to understand this macro:

```
#define SYMBOL_P(x) (((VALUE)(x)&0xff)==SYMBOL_FLAG)
```

I have no idea why this `&` operation is executed with `0xff`. Doesn't every number `& 0xff` equal itself?

Comment: check this http://edwinmeyer.com/Release_Integrated_RHG_09_10_2008/chapter02.html

Comment: Short answer, then: X is a long. So SYMBOLP() is a macro to test whether the rightmost 8 bits of the long match SYMBOL_FLAG.

Answer (score 1):

& is a bitwize operator (AND), (remember logic table?)

```
0 & 0 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

so what it does here?

0xff is the hexa of 255
in binary (DWORD): `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`

so assuming a number x= any_value

the representation of x can be like this

```
???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
```

each ? can be either 1 or 0

so applying bitwize operator & (AND) with the mask 0xff gives

```
  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
&
  00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
=
  00000000 00000000 00000000 ????????
```

for example

```
  00000000 00000000 00000011 00000011
&
  00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
=
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
  ^________________________^ ^______^
            zeroed             kept
```

Comment: understood, I forgot 0xff is an int , which should be 32 bits but not only 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The VALUE type in the Ruby source code is usually 32-bit or 64-bit, so the `& 0xFF` sets all the bits except the lowest 8 to 0.